# How to make clean links if I do no know the url

Tags: php

I try to design a web in different languages.

**How can make the link that gives a clean url?** Some pages are dynamic so, I do not know the url, I am searching for a way to make that links work in any page.

I know I can do this because it works in any page:

```
<a href='?lang=en'>en</a>
<a href='?lang=fr'>fr</a>
```

But, how to do that and be able to get a **clean url** like this?:

```
myDomain/someFolder/file.php // the default in English
myDomain/fr/someFolder/file.php // fr for French
```

(Beware that it is not just change fr to en. In English there is no /en/)

I have found that I have tu use a rewrite rule in the htaccess to change from myDomain/someFolder/file.php to myDomain/Folder/file.php?lang=en But this is not the point, my question is different, I ask: how to make clean links in the html if I do not know the url?

Comment: You would write your link in your `<a>` as per you want them to be. And then write the rule in your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: You don't need a rewrite rule in htaccess. That is just one way to do it. Another way is a little php script that sends a new location in the header. Another way is a scripted choice of a meta refresh tag. Another way is a JavaScript that has a language variable and reloads to the correct page.

Comment: @kainaw: I am confused. I have been hours searching for tutorials in the web. What is the best option to begin?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: @HamZa: my question is different. My question is how to make the link if I do not know the url. (I do not ask how to redirect later)

Comment: why not using a cookie to save users language selection? links won't get affected by this

Comment: @sharky: sounds interesting can you put a very basic example?

Comment: @D4V1D: that is the point, how can I write the link in the <a> if I do not know the url?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do, which is not anywhere as fancy as an .htaccess rewrite tool...

First, I would do something to get the current page name. This can be as simple as:

```
$pagename = "contactme.html";
```

Now, I have an array of available languages:

```
$languages = array('en'=>'English','fr'=>'French','es'=>'Spanish');
```

With that, I can slap this on the top of every page:

```
Select your language: <?php
foreach($languages as $ln=>$language)
    print " <a href='mysite.com/$ln/$pagename'>$ln</a> ";
```

That will spit out a list of abbreviations. Can they be little flags (a lot of people like those). Sure. Change `$ln` in the anchor to `<img src='$ln.png' border='0'>` and make sure you have all the images. Can they be in a form with a select list? Sure. Make a select list. Add an 'onchange' trigger to the form to reload to the correct URL. Can they be is a super-fancy rotating flash animation? Yes - if you really want to do something that silly.

Comment: this is interesting but it does not answer my question. I do not ask how to choose language. I ask how to make links if I do not know the url.